# How to apply one filter function to all fields in ORM?

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-orm

I have a Model class:

```
class Model_Feedback extends ORM {
    public function filters() {
        return array(
            'username' => array(
                array('trim'),
            ),
            'email' => array(
                array('trim'),
            ),
            'tel' => array(
                array('trim'),
            ),
            'text' => array(
                array('trim'),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Is there a way to `trim` all fields at once and not to define separate `trim` filter to every field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Kohana allows this via a wildcard as you can see in [`run_filter()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#run_filter), instead of setting a column as key, use `TRUE`

```
public function filters() {
    return array(
        TRUE => array(
            array('trim'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: be careful with that, in cases where you set for example database expressions `DB::expr()` as value, these would be altered to strings through the `trim` method...